# Width changes in material-ui TextField when label shrinks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component of a material-ui TextField, with some customizations. In this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-varahamihira-qumcr) is an example of it.

The problem is when I pass `shrink: true` in the InputLabelProps of the TextField. The component overrides the maximum width specified. Like this:

[image: CustomTextField]
The width should be like in the light blue section. The element in green is the shrinked label.

When `shrink: false` there is no problem, the component keeps the right width.

I have tried to set max-width on multiple elements in the component, but nothing has worked and I searched but couldn't find anything about this particular issue. Can someone point me in the direction to force this max-width on the right element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is you can select the `fieldset` element to control/apply the custom width to overall component. E.g. applying style using the `wrapper` class in `makeStyles`.

```
wrapper: {
  maxWidth: "45px",
  width: "45", //for testing
  "& fieldset": {
    minWidth: 44,
    paddingRight: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    marginLeft: 0
  }
},
```

[Updated sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-violet-w4v08?file=/src/CustomTextField.js:100-301)

Comment: Thanks! This works and helped me find that setting `min-inline-size: auto;` on that fieldset also makes it have the width I needed.

Comment: That's great...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mui it is better to use grids instead of component wrappers.
For instance you can insert your textfield inside a grid container and give it simple styling by providing xs, md, and xl. View docs for more info.

```
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item md={6} xs={12} xl={6}>
        <TextField.../>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

You can then add extra textfields inside the container by wrapping them with grid items and styling props.